# Visual Studio code extension wait for command completion

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a VS.code extension in Javascript that run's several commands. Some commands require user input, so the next command has to wait for completion of the previous command. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: same question: `await vscode.commands.executeCommand ('extension.copy_type', {new_type: 'users_copy'})` in vscode test just exists instantly (https://github.com/jonny64/vludik/blob/4b6c0fbe07dcf772a63dce6b83412d59ab99e33b/test/suite/extension.test.ts#L18)